# Can a settings bundle be displayed in-app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I'm working on my first iPhone app, and I'd really like to use a settings bundle to make the settings page that will allow users to change settings, but I'd like to have that settings page on my app, accessible by one of the tab bar items. Is this possible at all, or are settings bundles only used in the Settings app? And if it's not possible, what is the best way to have basic in-app settings? Should I just create an XIB and just make it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a settings bundle with your app, so that your customers can change different settings of your app but ONLY inside the settings app of iOS.

Here is a link explaining the process:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

I would recommend for you to create your own settings view controller either in a storyboard or xib since it is much more user friendly and you have total control over it. You can have your users settings stored either by NSUserDefaults, plist file or even keychain (which is encrypted).